# Can someone give me the name for this "area" of math?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm a math major and have come upon an section in Calculus II that has grabbed me by the horns. I'm currently working on sequences, infinite series, geometric series and touching on a bit of fractals. I can't get enough of this stuff.

I'm really interested in doing additional self study in this "area," but I'm unsure if this is classified as a specific branch of mathematics - maybe even a subcategory within calculus.

I'm keen to learn the name of this area of mathematics, presuming it has one. If anyone could provide it for me I'll happily use it as a starting point in my subsequent search. Additionally, any recommendations for a book (given my level in math) would be very appreciated.

Comment: Start by reading about real analysis

Comment: Analysis. Books by Rudin, Halmos, Tao, to mention a few.

Comment: Sequences could even be topology, for which I recommend Munkres' book, "Topology." (Math books always have very inventive names).

Comment: Thank you all very much, this has given me a great launching point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real analysis books mentioned in the comments are excellent but are not directly accessible from Calculus II. I recommend "Calculus" by Michael Spivak. It is used for an advanced introductory course at some universities and is full of "real" math (namely, proofs) but has essentially no prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to pick this up from the library. I appreciate the answer (and taking my specific level of math into account).