# Intro to analysis book?

Tags: real-analysis

I need an intro to analysis textbook that assumes you know absolutely nothing and that has alot of questions with answers in it. im a physics student moving into the math department so i have some higher level ( a few third year math class's) calculus but i really don't understand calculus or any kind of math theory at all. i also cant spare the time with work right now to take any class's so i want to learn it on my own hence the need for a textbook that assumes i know nothing about the topic.

I don't really care what it costs, i mean free resources are always good but i dont mind buying a couple textbooks for this.

Comment: See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006792/can-someone-give-me-the-name-for-this-area-of-math

Comment: IMHO this is your best option: http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Texts-Readings-Mathematics-No/dp/8185931941/ref=sr_1_16?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1415323399&sr=1-16